# groovy wrongly infers "off" as boolean instead of string

Tags: groovy

I've got a Jenkinsfile script in groovy which is processing a Java application's `application.properties` file, which I have just added to with

```
spring.main.banner-mode: off
```

In my script I read the `application.properties` file into a map in memory using a Jenkins add-in library `yamlRead` and then I output the value again into another file but it comes out as:

```
spring.main.banner-mode: false
```

That breaks my Java program on boot with a nasty spring boot error. The spring boot variable expects either OFF, FILE or CONSOLE.

I have no way to change `yamlRead` but I can change the output script which looks like this:

```
yaml.each {
    key, value -> B: {
            // some processing...
            sh "echo '$base$key=$value' >> $file"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I determine if the map actually has the boolean type (which would be bad since I can't change it) or whether the undesired cast to boolean happens in myy `echo >> file`?

Or could I somehow force groovy not to infer the booleanness when it reads the input, perhaps with quotes around "off"?

Comment: .properties are quite common in java and the separator there is `=` between key and value and not `:` - so you might tread careful there.  If you want to use YAML, you have to write `"off"` (needs to be a string so springboot can parse that to the enum)

Answer (score 4):

Everything is working as expected. Groovy is not your problem its YAML. The YAML reference says that 'off' is interpreted as 'false' as you can see here

https://yaml.org/refcard.html

The Jenkins yamlRead reads 'off' and transforms it to a boolean with value 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

as Thomas wrote: `off` is a reserved word in yaml format for boolean `false`

however you could quote it to force it to be a string:

```
spring.main.banner-mode: 'off'
```

in this case `spring.main.banner-mode` key will have a string value `off`

to check boolean `false` value you could use something like:

```
yaml.each {
    key, value -> B: {
        // some processing...
        sh "echo '$base$key=${ value==false? 'off' : value }' >> $file"
    }
}
```

**PS:** 
instead of calling `sh` to append to a file one key-value you could use following code:

```
def values = yaml.collect{k,v-> "$k=$v"}.join("\n")
writeFile( file: file, text: values )
```